# Use Patch with rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I am trying to test patch for devise user info using Rspec, the update url looks like this `# PATCH/PUT /api/users/1` but I am getting this error for all the following cases

Error `ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)`

Cases I tried

`patch :update, {'id'=> @api_user['user']['id'], 'user' => attributes_for(:normal_user)}`

`patch :update, 'id'=> @api_user['user']['id'], 'user' => attributes_for(:normal_user)`

`patch :update, 'id'=> @api_user['user']['id'], :params => {'user' => attributes_for(:normal_user)}`

And I tried this 
`patch :update,  :params => {'user' => create(:normal_user)}`. # this one has the id within

but gives this error

`No route matches {:action=>"update", :controller=>"api/users", :user=>#<User id: 227794695, email: "test11@example.com", created_at: "2020-05-03 08:51:55", updated_at: "2020-05-03 08:51:55", is_admin: nil, first_name: "test", last_name: "test">}` which make sence, the url should be `update/id`

Answer (score 0):

you should not put "update" after patch, since 
patch it self will automatically will route to update to user controller

this is the reason error message informed you given 2, expected 1 arguments

here is sample for your reference from update

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe 'User request', type: :request do
  it 'should update user email' do
    patch "/api/users/#{@api_user['user']['id']}",
          params: {
            user: {
              email: 'new_email_address@gmail.com'
            }
          },
          as: :json
    expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
  end
end
```

here is sample of /config/routes.rb for your reference to update users

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    resources :users, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
  end
end
```

Comment: I m not being able to use this route `api/user` it keeps giving me `No route matches {:action=>"/api/users/227794811", :controller=>"api/users", :format=>:json, :user=>{:password=>"newPassword"}}` even the route exist in api/user_controller

Comment: I just update my answer above, you can custom check your config/routes.rb for settings